# How to send to multiple subscribers using Triggered send API in the same API call?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, triggered-send

How to send to multiple subscribers using Triggered send API in the same API call?

I'm trying to send multiple email in the same triggered send API call. I'm getting a bad request error when i execute my request. I'm trying it with multiple "TO" objects in my request. Can this be even done? or this is technically not feasible?

```
{
    "To":{
        "ContactAttributes":{
            "SubscriberAttributes":{
                "Version_Number":"02/17"
            }
        },
        "Address":"xyz@yopmail.com",
        "SubscriberKey":"12344"
    },
    {
        "ContactAttributes":{
            "SubscriberAttributes":{
                "Version_Number":"02/17"
            }
        },
        "Address":"abc@yopmail.com",
        "SubscriberKey":"abc@yopmail.com"
    },              
    "From":{
        "Name":"",
        "Address":""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can.  You just need to send them as an array:

```
[{
    "From": {
        "Address": "me@here.com",
        "Name": "Me Here"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "you@there.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "you@there.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "City": "There",
                "State": "NY"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "From": {
        "Address": "notMe@here.com",
        "Name": "NotMe Here"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "youToo@there.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "youToo@there.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "City": "Anytowne",
                "State": "IA"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Also, you need to use the batch send, instead of the single send endpoint. Details here:

[I'm having trouble finding the link to the documentation.  Will update here.  I believe it's just the regular email endpoint, but instead of using /send at the end, use /sendBatch.]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The link you shared is for Push. Im trying to find something similar for email but unable to. Im using [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm).

Comment: Oops! I'll correct that.  I'm having trouble finding the documentation for this, but I know I've seen it.  What does the endpoint URI look like for email?  messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{your key}/send?

Comment: Thanks, per your recommendation i changed the send to sendBatch and it worked.